# How do you do a "day" picker in Ant Design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

They have the [DatePicker](https://3x.ant.design/components/date-picker/), but how about a "day" picker? I would like to have a "birthday" input without selecting the year, just the month and day. How can that be properly done in Ant Design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is using the date picket component, it can be done with `dateFormat`.

```html
const { DatePicker } = antd;


const { MonthPicker, RangePicker } = DatePicker;

const dateFormat = 'MM/DD';

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <DatePicker defaultValue={moment()} format={dateFormat} />
    <br />
   
  </div>,
  mountNode,
);
```